# Why am I Getting NoSuchFileException while copying a file in linux using Files.copy(). But works fine in windows.

Tags: java, linux, file, file-copying, java.nio.file

Hi I had to COPY a file from one folder to another. This is my code.

```
    File newFile = new File("/folder1/folder2/folder3/abc.txt");
    File currentFolder = new File("/folder1/folder2/folder4/" + File.separator);
    Files.copy(newFile.toPath(), new File(currentFolder.getPath() + File.separator + newFile.getName()).toPath(),
                StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

This worked fine for all those modules I was using previously. But for one particular module alone it threw the following error

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /folder1/folder2/folder3/abc.txt
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.copy(UnixCopyFile.java:520)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.copy(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:253)
at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1227)
at com.saru.utils.copyNewFileToReferenceFolder(Unknown Source)
at com.saru.utils.FileProcessorSaru.processingIncomingFile(Unknown Source)
at com.saru.utils.FileProcessorSaru.processOracleFinancial(Unknown Source)
at com.saru.utils.FileProcessorSaru.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The same code is working fine in windows. But getting the exception in linux.
Note: If you are going to ask whether the folder to which am copying exists, the answer is YES. Besides the exception is not showing the folder to which am copying the file. It is showing the folder where the file is currently present.

The input files IS present when this code is getting executed. But why does it saw NoSuchFile?

Please help me find what is wrong here.

Comment: What is the output of newFile.exist() ?

Comment: Does the Java process have permission to access the file and all parent directories?

Comment: It is unlikely SO can help you with your issue. You really should check if source file is present (something like `cat /folder1/folder2/folder3/abc.txt` executed from the same location you run your program should show if indeed file is there from *nix point of view)

Comment: @Henry Yes it has permission.

Comment: Hi @SercanOzdemir , the newFile.exist() throws false. But Why? I have not moved the file anywhere. It is present there at this point of time.

Answer (score 0):

You must be able to create a file, but you can't create a directory using a File class.

Just throw the    **IOException** at the start and mention the fileName.

OR

Wrap the code in try block and the catch the exception which is specified during the runtime and then specify the filename in the second line.

```
try {
    File newFile = new File("/folder1/folder2/folder3/abc.txt");
    File currentFolder = new File("/folder1/folder2/folder4/mention_file_name_here" +      File.separator);
    Files.copy(newFile.toPath(),new File(currentFolder.getPath() +File.separator + newFile.getName()).toPath(),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

}catch(IOException e) {
    e.printstacktrace();
}
```

Comment: I am not trying to create a directory. I have mentioned clearly that the directory IS present.